# how to speed up sympy-matrix of matrics calculation runtime

Tags: matrix, sympy, python-3.7

I've checked my code, there are no syntax error popping in the console, my matrix structures are correct, hence, mathematical  operations are feasible.
if i run my code it takes forever, the console never get to print out the result. I broke the matrix to chokes of smaller code, its still taking time to compute.

```
from sympy import Symbol,Matrix


az = Matrix([[1, 2, 3, 4,5, 6],
        [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 6],
        [4, 5, 6, 4, 8, 5],
        [5, 6, 5, 8, 9, 9],
         [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 5],
         [5, 6, 5, 8, 3, 9]])
fz = Matrix([[1,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,1,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,1,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,1,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,1,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,1]])
aa = Symbol('aa')
ff = Symbol('ff')
gen = Matrix([[aa, ff, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [ff,aa,ff,0,0,0],
            [0,ff,aa,ff,0,0],
                [0,0,ff,aa,ff,0],
                [0,0,0,ff,aa,ff],
                [0,0,0,0,ff,aa]])
inverse_genn = gen**-1

bz = Matrix([[2],
        [3],
        [3],
        [4],
        [5],
        [5]])
bzz = Matrix([[bz],[bz],[bz],[bz],[bz],[bz]])
solution = inverse_genn*bzz
_1st_displacement = solution[0][0]
_1st_solution = _1st_displacement.subs({aa:az,ff:fz})
print('type',solution[0].shape)
print('solution',solution[0][0])
print('##'*100)
print('displacement matrix', _1st_solution)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try make it easier to compute. Although an expression may be correct, it is not necessarily efficient for computation.

```
>>> eq=solution[0][0]
>>> count_ops(eq)
426
>>> s=eq.simplify()
>>> count_ops(s)
10
>>> s
2*(aa**2 - 1)/(aa**3 + aa**2 - 2*aa - 1)
>>> numer(s)/horner(denom(s))
(2*aa**2 - 2)/(aa*(aa*(aa + 1) - 2) - 1)
>>> h = _
>>> from time import time
>>> t=time(); e = h.subs(aa, az);print(time()-t)
0.0860941410065
```

Since `horner` does not apply itself to the numerator and denominator automatically, you have to use `as_numer_denom` to break up your simplified expression. Then you have to rebuild the expression. All together it looks like:

```
>>> be = zip(solution[0][0].simplify().as_numer_denom(), (1, -1))
>>> _1st_displacement = Mul(*[horner(b)**e for b,e in be])
```

CAUTION: this was written for an older version of SymPy. See comments below for modifications needed for newer SymPy.

Comment: thank you for your assistance, but please I don't how to integrate it into my code... can you add comments?

Comment: All of your code would be the same; before making the substitution into `solution[0][0]` you would need to simplify it. I added a little more to the answer above.

Comment: when i tried substituting the matrices, it raise a large chunk of error code, stating this TypeError: cannot add <class 'sympy.matrices.immutable.ImmutableDenseMatrix'> and <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Integer'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred... i'm still stuck

Comment: What should bzz look like? Is it a 6x6? with row 1 all 2? Try using `.subs({aa:az,ff:fz}, simultaneous=True).doit()`.

Comment: bzz is a 6x1 matrix containing 6x1 matrices.

Comment: You must be using an older version of SymPy -- I was not able to run your code in the latest version. But do try the `simultaneous` option and the final `doit` as suggested.

Comment: thanks, it ran.. I can see my answers... the result is a 6x6 matrix.. :))

Comment: whew! Glad that worked. FYI, if you update to the newer SymPy you might need to use BlockMatrix to create a matrix with matrix elements.